# angularjs surround bound data with brackets

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I need to surround a bound data value with square brackets so it will display as follows:

[somevalue]
Which I have done like so:

```
[<span ng-bind="person.id"></span>]
```

I can do this fine but I am running into an issue when I attempt to apply this to a dive which has a bound value, eg:

```
<div ng-bind-html="anotherValue | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

I want the [somevalue] to appear within the anotherValue div, but when I try the following code the second value isn't displayed:

```
<div ng-bind-html="anotherValue | trustAsHtml"> [<span ng-bind="person.id"></span>]</div>
```

I'm new to angularjs so I'm probably doing something completely stupid, my apologies if that is the case, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the way you are trying like so:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.person = {id: 2}
  $scope.anotherValue = 
  $sce.trustAsHtml('Hi[<span>'+$scope.person.id+'</span>]');
});
```

And in the markup:

```
<div ng-bind-html="anotherValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html replaces the inner-html of an element. So in this case the anotherValue would overwrite the `person.id`. If you move the inner span out the div it will become visible again

Comment: Oh ok I see thanks pyerwin. In that case I will find a workaround to get it displayed how I want.